# NGINX successfully serves static assets, but they do not render in the browser?

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

Chrome is showing all my static assets successfully downloading, and I can view them fine at, say:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/static/css/main.css
```

The initiator is identified as the tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
```

Images are being displayed, but no styles are rendering in the browser (they were before asking NGINX to serve them)

My NGINX.conf contains the following:

```
...
server {

    listen 80;

    location ^~ /static/  {
        root /home/ubuntu/clearsite/app/;
        autoindex off;
    }
...
```

I've disabled the cache in chrome and the same thing is happening on my mobile device.

My app is built in flask and uses uWSGI.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: One difference between my static files and those I see being downloaded while navigating other sites, is that chrome does not generate a preview for them in the developer tools. The valid CSS is still visible upon navigating to the file at the required URL however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NGINX config required one change:

```
    location ^~ /static/  {
        root /home/ubuntu/clearsite/app/;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }
```

I should have checked the chrome developer console; it was telling me there was a problem interpreting the CSS.

Comment: You sir, are a god among men. A hero among heroes. May the luck of Felix McWhiskers be forever with you.